# ESLint does not recognise `DocumentEventMap`, complaining no-undef

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a simple type defined as follows,

```
export type ClickEventProps = {
  handler: (event: MouseEvent) => void;
  additionalEvents?: Array<keyof DocumentEventMap>;
};
```

ESLint is complaining `DocumentEventMap` is undefined, giving a `no-undef`. Is there a way to fix it without disabling the rule for this line? Is it a bug in `@typescript-eslint`?

I have the current dev dependencies and versions for `@typescript-eslint`,

```json
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.7",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.7",
```

In .eslintrc.js, I have the following,

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['prettier', 'react', '@typescript-eslint'],
};
```

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "WebWorker"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "cypress-real-events"],
  },
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `"dom"` included in the "compilerOptions.lib` in your `tsconfig`?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes. Sorry, forgot to add some of the `tsconfig` to the original question. Updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This FAQ article in the typescript-eslint docs contains an answer to your question:

https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors

Relevant excerpts:

> The `no-undef` lint rule does not use TypeScript to determine the global variables that exist - instead, it relies upon ESLint's configuration.
>
> We strongly recommend that you do not use the `no-undef` lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.
>
> As of our v4.0.0 release, this also applies to types. If you use global types from a 3rd party package (i.e. anything from an `@types` package), then you will have to configure ESLint appropriately to define these global types. For example; the `JSX` namespace from `@types/react` is a global 3rd party type that you must define in your ESLint config.
>
> ...
>
> If you choose to leave on the ESLint `no-undef` lint rule, you can [manually define the set of allowed globals in your ESLint config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals), and/or you can use one of the [pre-defined environment (`env`) configurations](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments).

Answer (score 0):

Every EventTarget should have its own corresponding EventMap (even if no special event types are available for a given target, thus, resulting in an empty object). The EventMap of a given EventTarget could be retrieved as follows:

```
type DocumentEventMap = EventMap<Document>;
```

Comment: What is `EventMap`? `DocumentEventMap` is an interface provided by TypeScript https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.documenteventmap.html